# C# - Abort a looping thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-abort

I have threads that displays of data by looping on a certain interval by using Thread.Sleep.

```
public class myThread{


            public void threadPBAPI()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _PBAPI.Length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.writeLine();
                        Thread.Sleep(_interval * 1000);
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I want to abort stop this activity because, when i press a button a new set of data will load and want to perform this same activity from the start.

I tried doing Thread.Abort(); on a button Click event.
but it did not throw the ThreadAbortException.

on doing Thread.Join(); after Thread.Abort(); it throws the ThreadStateException "Thread Has not been started" when the thread is doing the actions its supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by using a global boolean flag and using break when the flag was set to true by button click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me:

set a global boolean flag -

```
isThreadAbort = false.
```

When its true, you can use

```
break;
```

or

```
i = _PBAPI.Length
```

Comment: you mean by checking a global boolean?

Comment: by using the Thread.Abort() you are stoping the thread not the for loop, by using break; or i = _PBAPI.Length now you are stoping the for loop